# JSONB data type is not upserting in Supabase in a Flutter Web Application

Tags: json, flutter, supabase

I have been creating a Web Survey App in Flutter that connects to a self-hosted Supabase. So far, I have successfully showed the questions retrieved from the database and now I am trying to save the answers to the database.

Here is the schema to create the table *responses*

```
CREATE TABLE responses (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    respondent_id UUID REFERENCES respondents(id) NOT NULL,
    assessment_cycle_id INT REFERENCES assessment_cycle(id) NOT NULL,
    response_date DATE,
    answers JSONB,
    finished BOOLEAN
);
```

The answers field will consist of an array with a pair of <int, int> where the first int is the question id and the second int is the numerical rating/answer for the question.

Here is the data model and repository for this table

```
class Response {
  final int? id;
  final String respondentId;
  final int assessmentCycleId;
  final DateTime responseDate;
  final Map<int, dynamic> answers;
  final bool? finished;

  Response({
    this.id,
    required this.respondentId,
    required this.assessmentCycleId,
    required this.responseDate,
    required this.answers,
    this.finished,
  });

  factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Response(
      id: json['id'],
      respondentId: json['respondent_id'],
      assessmentCycleId: json['assessment_cycle_id'],
      responseDate: DateTime.parse(json['response_date']),
      answers: Map<int, dynamic>.from(json['answers']),
      finished: json['finished'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'respondent_id': respondentId,
      'assessment_cycle_id': assessmentCycleId,
      'response_date': responseDate.toIso8601String(),
      'answers': answers,
      'finished': finished,
    };
  }
}
```

```
class ResponseRepository {
  final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

  ...

  Future<void> upsertResponse(Response res) async {
    try {
      print(
          'Entering upsert ${res.respondentId} ${res.assessmentCycleId} ${res.answers}');

      final checkIfExist = await supabase
          .from('responses')
          .select()
          .eq('respondent_id', res.respondentId)
          .eq('assessment_cycle_id', res.assessmentCycleId);

      if (checkIfExist.isEmpty) {
        await supabase.from('responses').insert({
          'respondent_id': res.respondentId,
          'assessment_cycle_id': res.assessmentCycleId,
          'response_date': res.responseDate.toIso8601String().split('T')[0],
          'answers': res.answers,
        });
      } else {
        await supabase.from('responses').update({
          'response_date': res.responseDate.toIso8601String().split('T')[0],
          'answers': res.answers
        }).eq('id', checkIfExist[0]['id']);
      }
      /*
      final response = await supabase.from('responses').upsert({
        'respondent_id': res.respondentId,
        'assessment_cycle_id': res.assessmentCycleId,
        'response_date': res.responseDate.toIso8601String().split('T')[0],
        'answers': res.answers,
      }, onConflict: 'respondent_id,assessment_cycle_id');
     */
    } catch (error) {
      throw Exception('Error updating answers: $error');
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried upserting (see the commented part) originally, but nothing happens, so I broke it to smaller steps. Basically, if an entry with the same respondent_id and assessment_cycle_id is existing, just update the *answers* field, replacing it with the new list. If not, create an entry.  I have printed the arguments to check if they are correct, and it showed the expected values. An example of the res.answers is `{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 1, 12: 0, 13: 4, 14: 4, 15: 4, 16: 3, 17: 3, 18: 3, 19: 3, 20: 1}`

Here is the snippet of the widget where it is called

```
class _SurveyPageState extends ConsumerState<SurveyPage> {
  ...
  final assessmentCycleId = 1;
  final ResponseRepository _responseRepository = ResponseRepository();
  final Map<int, dynamic> _answers = {};
  ...
  Future<void> _fetchInitialAnswer(String respondentId) async {

    print('Fetching Initial Answer');
    try {
      Response? initialAnswer = await _responseRepository.getResponse(
          respondentId, assessmentCycleId);
      if (initialAnswer != null) {
        _answers.clear();
        _answers.addAll(initialAnswer.answers);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Unexpected Error in fetching saved answers'),
      );
    }
  }
...
  Future<void> saveAnswers() async {
    try {
      Response res = Response(
          respondentId: respondentId,
          assessmentCycleId: assessmentCycleId,
          responseDate: DateTime.now(),
          answers: _answers);

      await _responseRepository.upsertResponse(res);
    } catch (error) {
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Unexpected Error in saving answers'),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _buildPage(String mainCategoryName, String? subCategoryName,
      List<Question> questions) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            mainCategoryName,
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.blue),
          ),
          if (subCategoryName != null)
            Text(
              subCategoryName,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.lightBlue),
            ),
          ...questions.map((question) => QuestionTile(
                question: question,
                onAnswered: (id, answer) {
                  setState(() {
                    _answers[id] = answer;
                  });
                },
                isNextClicked: _isNextClicked,
                answers: _answers,
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
   ...
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     ...
      body: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Question>>(
              ...
              return PageView.builder(
                    ...
                   if (_allQuestionsAnswered(
                      currentPageQuestions)) {
                       saveAnswers();
                     _controller.nextPage(
                        duration: const Duration(
                        milliseconds: 400),
                   curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                            ...
```

What changes should I do so I could upsert the entry? There were no error messages shown so I do not know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the data type being inserted from *<int,int>* to *<String, int>* so it can be accepted as **jsonb** data in Supabase/Postgres. The initial declaration of `final Map<int, dynamic> answers;` is changed to `final Map<String, dynamic> answers;`, and modifications in other parts of the code to complement this change. So from the previous value of answers `{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 1, 12: 0, 13: 4, 14: 4, 15: 4, 16: 3, 17: 3, 18: 3, 19: 3, 20: 1}`  it is now `{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 3, "5": 3, "6": 1, "7": 2, "8": 2, "9": 2, "10": 2, "11": 1, "12": 0, "13": 4, "14": 4, "15": 4, "16": 3, "17": 3, "18": 3, "19": 3, "20": 1 }`.  However, this created a new issue which will be a new stackoverflow question post. I cannot retrieve these values for initialization.