# Having problems in creating a data model and repository for a JSONB data type in Supabase for Flutter

Tags: flutter, jsonb, supabase

I am developing a Web Survey Form in Flutter that uses a self hosted Supabase for the database. I am now storing the answers and retrieving it for initialization and for further analysis. This question emerged after I solved my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78220561/jsonb-data-type-is-not-upserting-in-supabase-in-a-flutter-web-application). I am having difficulty in storing in a data model a field which is a **jsonb** data type, which consist of a list of *<String, int>*. Here is the schema used to create the table responses

```
CREATE TABLE responses (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    respondent_id UUID REFERENCES respondents(id) NOT NULL,
    assessment_cycle_id INT REFERENCES assessment_cycle(id) NOT NULL,
    response_date DATE,
    answers JSONB,
    finished BOOLEAN
);
```

A sample entry in the answers field is this:

```
{"1":1,"2":1,"3":3,"4":1,"5":0,"6":3,"7":3,"8":3,"9":2,"10":2,"11":1,"12":3,"13":3,"15":1,"14":3,"16":3,"17":3,"18":3,"19":2,"20":1}
```

Here is the current data model:

```
class Response {
  final int? id;
  final String respondentId;
  final int assessmentCycleId;
  final DateTime responseDate;
  final Map<String, dynamic> answers;
  final bool? finished;

  Response({
    this.id,
    required this.respondentId,
    required this.assessmentCycleId,
    required this.responseDate,
    required this.answers,
    this.finished,
  });

  factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Response(
      id: json['id'],
      respondentId: json['respondent_id'],
      assessmentCycleId: json['assessment_cycle_id'],
      responseDate: DateTime.parse(json['response_date']),
      answers: json['answers'] is Map<String, dynamic>
          ? Map<String, dynamic>.from(json['answers'])
          : {},
      finished: json['finished'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'respondent_id': respondentId,
      'assessment_cycle_id': assessmentCycleId,
      'response_date': responseDate.toIso8601String(),
      'answers': answers,
      'finished': finished,
    };
  }
}
```

Here is the repository.

```
class ResponseRepository {
  final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

  Future<Response?> getResponse(
      String respondentId, int assessmentCycleId) async {
    try {
      final response = await supabase
          .from('responses')
          .select()
          .eq('respondent_id', respondentId)
          .eq('assessment_cycle_id', assessmentCycleId)
          .single();

      if (response.isNotEmpty) {
        print('Response: $response');
        return Response.fromJson(response);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw Exception('Error fetching questions: $error');
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to print the value of *response* to check, and it retrieved the results correctly including *answers*. However, in the Survey Page where the questions and answers will be printed, when I tried to initialize the value of answers, it was empty.

```
class _SurveyPageState extends ConsumerState<SurveyPage> {
  ...
  final Map<String, dynamic> _answers = {};


  Future<void> _fetchInitialAnswer(String respondentId) async {

    try {
      Response? initialAnswer = await _responseRepository.getResponse(
          respondentId, assessmentCycleId);
      if (initialAnswer != null) {
        print('Initial Answer ${initialAnswer.toJson()}');
        _answers.clear();
        _answers.addAll(initialAnswer.answers);
        print('Answers: $_answers');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Unexpected Error in fetching saved answers'),
      );
    }
  }
...
```

Here, I tried to print the *initialAnswer* in the line `print('Initial Answer ${initialAnswer.toJson()}');`  which is of a Response type that was retrieved from the *getResponse*. It printed all values except the *answers* which is just `{}`. So it means the field in the data model is incorrect.

```
 answers: json['answers'] is Map<String, dynamic>
          ? Map<String, dynamic>.from(json['answers'])
          : {},
```

How will I rectify this, and later assigned the values so it can be initialized correctly? I am really new to Flutter and Supabase and relying in Microsoft Bing/Copilot but it keeps showing deprecated solutions so I am stuck. Thanks in advance!